# How C# SHA512 shaM ComputeHash should be implemented Angular10 or Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, angular

I have a C# function as below:

```
using(SHA512 shaM = new SHA512Managed()) {
  var hash = shaM.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(nonce + appKey));
  StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(hash.Length * 2);
  foreach(byte b in hash)
  hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);

  secret = hex.ToString();
}
```

I need to create a javascript function that matches the code above so that the end result for both C# and JS is the same.

This is the result of my hexhash:

```
5e7ae43531bffecfd539e0bd129f241b4365e92ba934484aba3f045203cf1157f680766c4ddaf0c772a9c870a68d252869da6db80fbcae644fa5e92725bf5be0
```

I have never come across this kind of function so I need what exactly happing in the above function and how do I need to convert in angular
also, I found the below package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-sha512
and imported but I am not sure how to add nonce and appkey to that function

I am not sure it's the right thing to use the above npm package
Please guide me on how can I proceed?

Comment: `sha512(nonce + appkey);` and you're done.

Comment: The hash you get doesn't tell us anything since you have not provided what `nonce` and `appkey` contains. We cannot in any (manageable) way "decode" the hash to know the original values.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen 
nonce:  DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ")
appKey:"OTtLfrHQmFmgf68n"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Nonce` is a cryptographic term. It's a number or value intended to be used only once to prevent replay attacks. It can be as effective as an IV (Initialization Vector) in algorithms lacking IV in their implementations. Therefor it is prepended to the actual message to be hashed. In this case the message is `appkey`. (Or rather the value in the variable `appkey`).

To get the same result in javascript you need to know the values of `nonce` and `appkey`. Then call the hash function to generate the hash just as in C# by concatenating `nonce` and `appkey`:

```
let hash = sha512(nonce + appkey);
```

**Edit:**

After your comment about the contents of `nonce` and `appkey` something like this should yield the correct result:

```
let nonce = new Date().toISOString();
let appkey = 'OTtLfrHQmFmgf68n';
let hash = sha512(nonce + appkey);
```

Remember that nonce changes with time so if you need to compute a hash on one end and verify on the other then you need to store the nonce so the verifier can have the same nonce.

Here are the [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hhqGDJ) and [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6dtk2qm8/1/) examples that both yield the same result.

Comment: can this be achieved without a npm package?

Comment: @vinuta: Yes. Include the functionality manually or just implement the SHA-512 algorithm yourself. Using npm is though the easiest way to do it.

Comment: I just tested it in both ways it's working correctly thank you so much and thanks for the explanation